# Linq: how to select certain text "True" or "False" for corresponding boolean values?

Tags: c#, linq

The following query is used to get data in which flagchecked is boolean.

```
var reducedList = alarmlog.Select(e => 
new { 
    e.ID, 
    e.alarmname, 
    e.alarmmessage, 
    e.metername, 
    e.starttime, e.flagchecked 
}).ToList();
```

I am using reducedList  to export data to excel. Excel displays boolean values as checkboxes.I would like to have text "True" or "Done"  for corresponding boolean true/false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the ternary/conditional operator: [?: Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
var reducedList = alarmlog.Select(e => new 
{ 
    e.ID, 
    e.alarmname, 
    e.alarmmessage, 
    e.metername, 
    e.starttime, 
    flagchecked = e.flagchecked ? "Done" : "Not Done" }).ToList();
```

---

The conditional operator works like:  `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`

This means that: `e.flagchecked ? "True" : "False";` works the *same* as:

```
private string ConvertTrueFalseString(bool value)
{
    if(value)
        return "True";
    else
        return "False";
}

var reducedList = alarmlog.Select(e => new 
{ 
    e.ID, 
    e.alarmname, 
    e.alarmmessage, 
    e.metername, 
    e.starttime, 
    flagchecked = ConvertTrueFalseString(e.flagchecked)).ToList();
```

So, for this: `e.flagchecked ? "Done" : "Not Done"`. If *(e.flagchecked == true)* it returns **"Done"** and when *(e.flagchecked == false)* it returns **"Not Done"**

You might check the [?: Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) link I posted above.

Comment: Invalid anonymous type declaratory

Comment: I don't know why you get that exception could you offer more detail?

Comment: I edited it, when doing an expression, you need to declare a property name, i forgot.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yup its working. Can you please also include else part. I mean if its False it should be "Not Done"

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about how it works, I'll add some extra info.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen ah that makes everything so clear. I always avoided ternary operators because I did not quite understand them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var reducedList = alarmlog.Select(e => new {
    e.ID,
    e.alarmname,
    e.alarmmessage,
    e.metername,
    e.starttime,
    flagchecked = e.flagchecked ? "Done" : "Undone"
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Invalid anonymous type declaratory

Answer (score 0):

```
reducedList.ForEach(x => x.flagchecked == "True" ? x.flagchecked = "Done" : x.flagchecked = "Undone");
```

You can do this after you instantiate the `reducedList`.